# Handling Double Bit Exceptions/GPU Errors in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cuda

We're using Keras and Tensorflow for a deep learning application on some machines in Google Cloud Platform using K80 GPUs.

We've been having some problems with Double Bit ECC (DBE) errors. According to the official documentation https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/dynamic-page-retirement/index.html:

> Applications will receive a DBE event notification for graceful exit,
>   and no further context will be created on the GPU until the DBE is
>   mapped out.

When these errors occur our application goes to using 100% CPU. We don't know what it is doing at this point, but we'll work on adding some more ways of monitoring it.

My question is how does my application receive these DBE event notifications? Is it a SIGTERM, some type of error I should be catching when call Keras, or something else I should be doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The CUDA runtime will produce an error if the GPU fails in a way which renders it unusable. How those errors get handled by the frameworks you are using is a question about the frameworks, rather than anything related to CUDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a GPU gets uncorrectable ECC error, it is not directly reported to any app.
Kernel driver logs Xid 48 followed by Xid 63 and the GPU becomes effectively disabled until after it's reset either by nvidia-smi utility or by rebooting the machine.
See details here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html

From the application standpoint the effect is that at some point in time kernels start failing to launch. Depending on an application you may get an error reported. I believe tensorflow does check for the errors most of the time, and the app will eventually fail with an assertion. It's likely that the failure messages will not have any indication that the crash has anything to do with the ECC error.

The very first failure after detection of the uncorrectable error may look particularly puzzling. At that moment the error causes some ongoing operation to abort and you may eventually get fairly wide range of possible errors reported. Again, none of them will say anything about ECC errors and you will need to check for that yourself.